# how to use glmnet without regularization

Tags: glm, logistic-regression, glmnet, regularized

I have read that glmnet can be used without regularization, i.e. it can be used as a regular glm. I am writing a thesis and trying to avoid using to many different packages, so it would be convenient to use glmnet to do a regular glm logistic regression fitting. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Setting both tuning parameters alpha and lambda to zero should give you a "normal" logistic regression without regularization.

Comment: I would add, I think setting lambda to zero is sufficient.